# SQL Server : stored procedure add table content to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add the results from a query by parameter to another table using a stored procedure?

Here is my select query text:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.PortfolioH.Epic, 
    dbo.PortfolioH.AlertRatings,
    dbo.UserAccounts.Email, 
    dbo.PortfolioH.UserN
FROM            
    dbo.PortfolioH 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.UserAccounts ON dbo.PortfolioH.UserN = dbo.UserAccounts.UserN
GROUP BY 
    dbo.PortfolioH.Epic, 
    dbo.PortfolioH.AlertRatings, 
    dbo.UserAccounts.Email,
    dbo.PortfolioH.UserN
HAVING        
    (dbo.PortfolioH.AlertRatings = N'yes')
```

I want to append to table `AlertEmails` where `dbo.PortfolioH.Epic = @Epic`

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to select and insert within the stored proc, or use the results of the stored proc to insert?

Comment: I wanted to select and insert in to the AlertsEmails table with the SP

Comment: Does `AlertsEmails` table have any columns apart from those returned by your query? If yes, what value do you want to insert into the other columns?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the standard `INSERT.....SELECT` construct, which takes the data to be inserted from a query, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AlertsEmails (Epic, AlertRatings, Email, UserN, AlertType)

SELECT        dbo.PortfolioH.Epic, dbo.PortfolioH.AlertRatings,
dbo.UserAccounts.Email, dbo.PortfolioH.UserN, 1 As AlertType

FROM            dbo.PortfolioH LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.UserAccounts ON dbo.PortfolioH.UserN = dbo.UserAccounts.UserN

GROUP BY dbo.PortfolioH.Epic, dbo.PortfolioH.AlertRatings, dbo.UserAccounts.Email,
dbo.PortfolioH.UserN
HAVING        (dbo.PortfolioH.AlertRatings = N'yes') ;
```

It just runs the query, but instead of returning a result set, inserts the resulting rows into the table. Note that I've added the AlertType column in the `INSERT` part and added a fixed value in the `SELECT` part, as they must match exactly.

Comment: Thanks, Where do i put the where clause for Select Epic = @Epic

Comment: As you would within a simple `SELECT`. After the `FROM` and before the `GROUP BY` in this case. Consider this is just a normal `SELECT`, with the difference that its results will get inserted into a table instead of returned.